# Building Forms for Outlook 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, forms, vba, outlook

I was just introduced to the concept of Outlook forms. I don't know if this will solve my problem but here is what I want to do:

I want to be able to have employees who are inside the company fill out some forms. So all I have to do is create the form and PUSH it to their Outlook? After they fill out the form, can I capture the data somehow? Has anyone does this before? Can someone recommend a good tutorial/examples?

**Update:** The Outlook->Access option seems like a great one, but it seems like the form must be emailed by someone. In other words, if someone wants to fill out any form they first have to be emailed a form. What if a person wants to just fill out a form? How would he do it if he has no access to the Access database?

Comment: does the below answer your question? anything else I can clarify or help you with on this subject?

Comment: thank you very much. i have added one more part to the question, please see edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are three options:

1. [This page](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=35) is a really good jump page for custom forms in Outlook. In fact, that whole site is pretty good with lots of [examples](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=45) and links like [Outlook Forms Step-by-Step Tutorial](http://qvlweb.blogspot.com/2009/02/outlook-forms-step-by-step-index.html).
2. However, if you also have Access 2007, I'd actually recommend something simpler and easier to create email forms that can be sent to users and collect back all of the information. Once I discovered this in Access 2007 I never went back to custom Outlook forms.

   Basically, you create an Access db with the data you want to collect and then in the "External Data" tab in Access 2007, you click "Create E-mail" and a wizard will walk you through creating an email with the form in the body (which is either HTML or InfoPath, depending on which one you choose). You send this to your users (you can have a recipient list in a table as well in your Access DB) and they fill out the form (I used it for surveys) and then they click submit. It goes back to your Outlook in a special folder and as soon as you open Outlook, it will synch it with the database. Then you can slice and dice all of that database information.

   Here are some great tutorials on this:

   - [Demo: Collect data in Access 2007 by
     using e-mail](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/demo-collect-data-in-access-2007-by-using-e-mail-HA010252713.aspx)
   - [How to integrate Microsoft Access
     and Outlook 2007](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-integrate-microsoft-access-and-outlook-2007-239804/)
3. Finally, if you just want to collect back much simpler information, like "Yes", "No", "Maybe", the easiest way is to create voting buttons. Go to New Message -> Options - Voting Buttons. You can customize this if needed by separating your choices with a semi-colon `;`.

In **#2** and **#3** above, these are scenarios to initiate data collection.

There are other situations where someone doesn't need a prompt via email to fill something out right there, but rather just submit a form (like an expense report, or a gas mileage report). **#1** above (Outlook custom forms) is generally better choice in that scenario, but:

- Outlook forms have typically been
  harder to deploy and teach people to
  use (there are things like "public
  forms", "private forms", etc.)
- Outlook forms have been, in practice,
  been replaced by other technologies.
  In particular, [InfoPath/Forms Server](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/forms-server/CH010062637.aspx) and
  [Sharepoint Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544154.aspx). This is because neither
  of those two technologies requires
  users to do a whole lot other than
  follow a link to fill out a form. I used to know, about 10 years ago, many companies who tried to use Outlook forms and most of them gave up development of them in favor of other technologies.

This isn't to say that Outlook forms are bad in any way. If you don't have other technologies available to serve as a Forms Server, then this could be a decent option to consider.

To look at other semi-lightweight ways of form submission, you can use MS Word templates as the front end and have them update an Access DB. Here are a couple of good articles on this:

1. [Import Data Directly from Word
   Forms to Access Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155434(office.10).aspx)
2. [How do I... Transfer data from a
   Word form to an Access database?](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/howdoi/?p=187)

Comment: +1 for the option to use Access 2007.  It is simply one of the most amazing things ever.  No joke.  We deployed this for a small project in my company and it made the collection and analysis of form data ridiculously simple.

Comment: otaku that you for your update, but i would like to know specifically whether i can use outlook to access for employees that just need to fill out some form rather than some manager of the DB emailing them the form

Comment: @I__: do you mean like a form someone opens in Outlook, they fill out, push "save" or "send" or "submit", and it populates an Access DB?

Comment: yes exactly. or it doesnt have to be outlook, it can be in a folder on a network drive. maybe even a word document that someone fills out. anything that is easy to fill out and press SUBMIT instead of writing my own aplciation to do this

Comment: @I__: Ah, gotcha. If this is the case, and you have Access, this is the kind of stuff Access was built for. You could create a custom Access DB with forms, but to use your idea of using Word forms as the front end, I've updated the above.