# why can't I see voting buttons in a bloomberg email?

Tags: outlook, excel, outlook-2003, bloomberg, vba

I'm sending an email from Outlook 2003 (soon to be 2007) to a colleague's Bloomberg email address.  I added voting buttons to it.  Outlook users can all see the buttons, but the colleague who's reading the email in his Bloomberg console cannot.  Is there any way I can get those voting buttons to be displayed to him?  If not, are there any options available to me that will allow me to use a click event to track a recipient's response to a yes/no question?  At the moment I'm doing this all manually, but the goal is to create a VBA program to automate the sending of these emails and the tracking of recipient responses.

Thanks,
Diana

Comment: When you upgrade to 2007, will you also be getting Access 2007? If so, I've got a solution for you!

Comment: Yes - we'll be getting MS Office 2007

Comment: Great, see answer below.

Comment: does the below answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Voting buttons are a proprietary Outlook feature and will only work in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Check out bullet #2 in this answer for HTML/InfoPath forms sent via Outlook and logged back in your Access DB: [Building Forms for Outlook 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196081/building-forms-for-outlook-2007/3230789#3230789)

Comment: I don't have Access 2007 yet, so I can't replicate the suggested solution.  I created a form in Access 2003 but am unable to embed it in the body of an Outlook 2003 email.  I did play with a sample data access page to see if I could embed that in the body, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Diana Tortolini: Yeah, this doesn't work with Office 2003. The only thing I would suggest right now before your company upgrades is to download a trial of Office 2007, put it on a VM or another computer and go about learning how to do this before your company upgrades.